# Find id from sqlite by any item

Tags: android, sqlite, find, android-sqlite

I have to find "id" in database and I try this way but I can't solve it.  Could you help me. Thanks a lot.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.XouOnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {

            String text = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(arg2);


            Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());
            String query = "SELECT name, id FROM tableDB WHERE name = '" + text + "'"; // I think problem is here
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

             id_position = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));

            go_detail();
        }
    });
```

// this part is OK

```
private void go_detail(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Detail_page.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", (int) name_ids[id_position]);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think error is in your `go_detail` function. try adding a parameter, such as `go_detail(int id_position){....}` right now, it cant get the id without parameter

Comment: No. I tried every line one by one. And definately problem is this line

String query = "SELECT def, id FROM tuncDB WHERE def = '" + second + "'";

Comment: but how do you expect to get the value of `id_position` in your `go_detail` function